# Retrieve HTML from webpage in PyQt

Tags: python, html, pyqt4

I currently have a python script running, logging in the given user to the web page and navigating to a different page on the site after logging. What I'm aiming for i to get the raw HTML of the final page **after** it is finished loading. I have tried different variation of the Render class but it seems to throw a "frame is not an attribute of Render" error. Like I said my main goal is just to get the HTML of the page. What am I doing incorrect?

```
url = "https://firstwebpage.com/"
url3 = "https://finaldestinationpage.com" #the page that I want the HTML from
username = "username"
password = "password"




import sys, signal

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, app, url):
         QWebPage.__init__(self)
         self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
         self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
         app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
         self.frame = self.mainFrame()


def JSEval(code):
    return webpage.mainFrame().evaluateJavaScript(code)

def onLoadStarted():
    print("Loading started: %s" % webpage.mainFrame().url().toString())

def onLoadFinished(result):

    print("Loading finished: %s" % webpage.mainFrame().url().toString())
    if not result:
        print("Request failed")
        return

    JSEval("_form = document.getElementsByName('loginForm')[0];")

    JSEval("_form.username.value='%s';" % username \
        + "_form.password.value='%s';" % password \
        + "_form.submit();")
    print("Login data sent")
    if webpage.mainFrame().url().toString() == url3:
        r = Render(app,url3)  
        html = r.frame.toHtml()  #Here is where the "frame" error comes in
        print(html)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
webpage = QWebPage()
webpage.connect(webpage, SIGNAL("loadFinished(bool)"), onLoadFinished)
webpage.connect(webpage, SIGNAL("loadStarted()"), onLoadStarted)
webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))   #where user is initally logged in
webpage.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url3))
web = QWebView()
web.setPage(webpage)
web.show()


sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Render` class, you set the `frame` attribute in your handler for `loadFinished`, but when you use it you try to access it immediately after you created your `Render` instance. By that time chances are very high that the page hasn't been loaded yet and therefore the signal has't fired, so `r.frame` will not yet exit.

If you want to get the html content of the page, you can only do it after the page has finished loading, so it would be better to do it in your signal handler.

Oh, and you shouldn't call `app.exec_()` in `Render.__init__`.